# NW.js loosing transparent after OS hibernation

Tags: javascript, node-webkit, nw.js

I am working on an App for windows, with Node webkit version: '0.17.4'. 
I just figured out that the transparency was disabled after each hibernation wake up + app restoration fromm system tray.

```
win.on('minimize', function () {
    var tray = new gui.Tray({title: 'Ephemeride', icon: 'images/icon.png'});
    // Hide window
    win.hide();
    // Show window and remove tray when clicked
    tray.on('click', function () {
        win.show();
    });
});

win.on('restore', function () {
    win.resizeTo(900, 600);

});
```

Any ideas ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly a find this solution, to reload chrome runtime.

```
var tray;
win.on('minimize', function () {
    tray = new gui.Tray({title: 'Ephemeride', icon: 'images/mini-icon.png'});

    // Hide window
    win.hide();
    // Show window and remove tray when clicked
    tray.on('click', function () {
        win.show();
        tray.remove();
        chrome.runtime.reload();
    });
});

win.on('restore', function () {
    win.resizeTo(900, 600);
});
```

Hope this will help.